# OEL5 Linux Direct user login via putty doesn't work but able to switch to the user after logging in from another account

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, oracle-linux

I have a user X on OEL Linux that is active but whenever i try connecting to it via Putty , i get access denied.

But if i login to the same server via another user and switch to User X , then it allows.

Wonder what i need to configure so m able to login directly via putty for User X.

Comment: What do the logs have to say about it?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I directly get access denied at the prompt. Should I be checking syslog?

Comment: You need to be checking both the system log and the security log.